# Verifying if a file exist (script shell)

Tags: shell

This is my code:

```
 nb_lignes=`wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f1`
 for i in $(seq $(($nb_lignes - 1)) )
 do
 machine=`head $1 -n $i | tail -1`
 machine1=`head $1 -n $nb_lignes | tail -1`
 ssh  root@$machine -x " scp /home/file.txt root@$machine1:/home && rm -r /home/file.txt"
 done
```

I'd like to verify if file.txt exist in such machine before the scp et rm ,Please i ask how can i modify this script ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a `fi` in your code, but I don't see any `if`. Can you please review your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `test` command: `test -f file && scp ...`

```
     ssh  root@$machine -x " test -f /home/file.txt && scp /home/file.txt
root@$machine1:/home && rm -r /home/file.txt"
```

Comment: Please i have this error at run: Host key verification failed.
lost connection
have you an idea please ?

Comment: That means your `ssh` connection failed due to authorization issue. Add sshkeys. Here's how to do it: [ssh keygen](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html)

Comment: $machine1 is a variable, i add a quote ?

Comment: No, there's nothing with the command/script. ssh fails due to sshkey mismatch/no keys. You have to add the keys and follow that link for instructions on how to add ssh keys.

Comment: i have teste with other command ssh   root@$machine -x "java..." and it works without pb

Comment: Well, the error you have mentioned is because of ssh key issue.

Comment: Please can you guide me i'm beginner with ssh, i should generate ssh-keygen for each machine ?

Comment: i have added ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub root@$machine but it display /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
have you an idea please ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18419/discussion-between-kingsindian-and-user1735757)

Comment: This is the first time that I participate in chat here. Did you get my lines?

Comment: From your machine where you run the ssh command run "ssh-keygen" --> You mean the machine where i run the script ?